# Convert imagemap to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

There is one way to convert one image map to canvas, I need to know how to do complex maps and highlight when the mouse is over.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this Question & Answer?

"Maps on Canvas are currently an open issue with HTML5."

[Does (HTML5) Canvas have the equivalent of an image map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932141/does-html5-canvas-have-the-equivalent-of-an-image-map/2933088#2933088)

Comment: I have checked but this is not my question. In this question he asks for an image map on canvas. I know there is no posible. The answer was: and image map over the canvas, another solution is a collision test. This is useful, but i want to translate image map polygonal coordinate to create custom shapes in canvas.

Comment: Thanks you Daniel, I have solved it, with a collision detect. The links you send me doesnt work, one is for image map, which canvas doesnt have, and the other is for canvas of silverlight. Im working in html5.